# Matrix multiplication with class operator

Tags: c++, class, matrix

i am working on multiplication of matrix
it is something like

```
m5 = m2 * m3;
cout << "m2 * m3 is : " << endl<< m5 << endl;
```

and this is my code

```
const Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &a)
{
   Matrix temp(a.row,a.col);
   for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j<col; j++)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k<a.row; k++)
        {
            temp.data[i][j] = temp.data[i][j] + data[i][k] * a.data[k][j];
        }
      }
  }
 return temp;
}
```

However, there is an error always showing at my printing function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const Matrix &a)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
      {
        output << a.data[i][j] << "\t";
      }
    output << "" << endl;
   }
   return output;
}
```

seems there has a problem on a.data[i][j] which i dont know what's the problem
it works fine on addition.
it is showing an error {data0x005fba90{0xfeeefeee{???}}
can anybody give any advice or suggestions or help on this situation
this is my copy constructor

```
 Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix&m2)
{
  row = m2.row;
  col = m2.col;
  setUp(row, col);
  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j<col; j++)
      {
          data[i][j] = 0;
      }
  }  
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
      {
        data[i][j] = m2.data[i][j];
      }
  }
}
```

this is the set up and default

```
Matrix::Matrix()
{
 row =0;
 col = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j<col; j++)
    {
        data[i][j] = 0;
    }
 }

}
Matrix::Matrix(int a, int b, double d[], int c)
{
 row = a;
 col = b;
 setUp(row, col);
 int counter = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        data[i][j] = d[counter];
        counter++;
    }
 }
 }
```

and the set up

```
 void Matrix::setUp(int a, int b)
{
 row = a;
 col = b;
 data = new double*[row];
 for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) data[i] = new double[col];
 }
```

Comment: *However, there is an error always showing at my printing function* Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Shouldn't the temp matrix have `this->row` and `a.col` dimensions?

Comment: but if i didnt use any operator and it does work, what is the different between using an operator and not

Comment: In your copy-constructor, the first set of loops is useless, since you will overwrite the data directly afterwards. Also, we still need to see the class definition as well as the constructor taking the rows and column arguments, and probably the `setUp` function too. Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `Matrix` constructor, or the class definition, it's hard to say for certain, but if you look at this expression

```
temp.data[i][j] + data[i][k] * a.data[k][j]
```

Depending on what `data` is, if you don't explicitly initialize the `data` member in the constructor when you create `temp` then its contents will not automatically be initialized, and the contents will be *indeterminate* and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Another possible source of problems might be the lack of a copy-constructor, or a faulty copy-constructor. This is a problem since you return `temp` by value which invokes the copy-constructor.

Comment: i have a copy constructor function but it looks like doesnt help